# Running a method between each method call

Tags: ruby

Basically I want something like this:

```
some_method do
  method1()
  method2()
  method3()
end
```

where between each of these 3 methods, there would be `sleep 5`, I just don't want to repeat `sleep 5` after each and every method call. Is there a way to define `some_method` such as, between each method call, a particular method like `sleep 5` is being executed? I don't want to pollute my code by inserting a bunch of `sleep` commands after each and every method call.

Comment: Create a function that takes a list of functions, and executes each in a loop, and adds a sleep after each call. Of course this is only feasible if each function takes 0 arguments, else you'd need to wrap each function in a 0-arity lambda. Idk Ruby, but if it's capable, a macro could do this too.

Answer (score 2):

If, as in the example, the methods take no arguments or blocks, and the return values are not used, you could do the following.

```
module M
  def method1
    puts "method 1"
  end
  def method2
    puts "method 2"
  end
  def method3
    puts "method 3"
  end
end

class A
  include M
  def method4
    puts "method 4"
  end
  def execute_methods
    M.instance_methods.each { |m| send m; sleep 5 }
  end
end

A.new.execute_methods
  # method 1
  # method 2
  # method 3
```

One advantage of including a module containing the methods to be executed is that you can add, remove or rename methods in the module without changing any other code. This technique might be potentially useful, for example, when executing a series of validation methods that each return `true` or `false`:

```
def validate(obj)
  M.instance_methods.all? { |m| send m, obj }
end
```

This is also an example of methods that have arguments and whose return values are used.

Comment: Neat, but it's a little restrictive isn't it?  Any arbitrary function you wanted to do this with would need to have a delegate in the module.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I don't understand what "delegate in the module" means.

Comment: You would need to make a wrapper around any function you wanted to use wouldn't you? Like say I wanted to do this with the built-in function `map`. I would have to create a wrapper function inside the module that calls the built-in `map` wouldn't I?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, yes, but I'm assuming the OP is not referring to built-in methods.

Comment: OK. And just out of curiosity, where is the delay being added? Does Ruby have a special syntax for that?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, just before you posted your last comment I realized I didn't include the delay, so I added it.

Answer (score 0):

Note, I don't know Ruby, so this will be in a javascripty flavour of pseudocode, and won't make use of any "special features" of Ruby.

This is probably the simplest way to achieve what you're looking for:

```
function execute_in_sequence(delay, fs) {
    foreach(f in fs) {
        f();
        sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
function p() {
    print(1);
}

execute_in_sequence(500,
    [p, p, p]
);
```

You could also get rid of the explicit list using variadic functions, which could let you write it as:

```
execute_in_sequence(500,
    p, 
    p, 
    p
);
```

In this example, `p` is pretty simple. To do this with functions that require arguments, you would need to wrap the calls in a lambda first.

Also note that the obvious flaw is that you can't return any values this way. All of the functions must operate soley through side effects, which limits the use of this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible some_method implementation.
Parameters are the methods names as symbol (i.e :method1 for method1()), and if a block is given, it's executed after each method call.

```
def method1
  puts "Method1"
end

def method2
  puts "Method2"
end

def method3
  puts "Method3"
end

def some_method(*methods)
  methods.each{|m|
    send m
    yield if block_given?
  }
end

some_method(:method1, :method2, :method3) do
  puts "  Waiting 5 sec."
  sleep 5
end
```

It returns :

```
Method1
  Waiting 5 sec.
Method2
  Waiting 5 sec.
Method3
  Waiting 5 sec.
```

With some tweaks and more logic, you could also send parameters to the different methods and saves what the methods return in an Array.